# Terminate query execute in oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I have asp.net page which allow users to run select queries on oracle data base. then result is shown on web page as a data table.

Some time users may enter queries that impact badly on DB due to long and deep query execution.

Is there any possibility to mention time out for each query run on DB . If query runs longer than specified time execution must be stop on database.

Comment: Welcome to SE: If you like my answer and it solves your problem please accept it as the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem on the application or DB side:

Application Side: SQLQueryTimeout
You can set an SQLQueryTimeout generally for all Statements on the Driver, or Individually with CommandTimeout for a certain command. If a query takes longer than that a TRAP is invoked and you get an Exception whcih you can Handle.

The Second possibility is to set a Timeout for an Oracle-user. If your Web-Application connects to the database via a shared user (as it should be) you can use ALTER USER to set a User Profile which will enforce a MAX CPU LIMIT, which is in effect a time-limit on all SQL Statments issued by that user.

The beauty of the second solution is that the Database enforces the rule, so you don't have to worry about your application code where you might miss a line...

Comment: if i use first scenario will this CommandTimeout property stop execution of query in DB

Comment: Yes! If you use the driver timeout, it will send an interruption command to the database and the query will stop executing. The only edge case is when you server Thread dies or is disconnected before the server can activate the timeout - then usually nothing is stopping the active query from running a long time... But this will not happen often with a stable applicationserver